# Swift - JSON Add the key names into an array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I want to take the JSON key names and add them into an array.

```
{
   "name": "Battleaxe, tactical",
   "price": 2650,
   "level": 5,
   "bulk": "1",
   "special": ["Analog"],
   "damage": "1d8 S",
   "source": "Incident at Absalom Station",
   "hands": 1,
   "critical": "Wound",
   "category": "Uncategorized",
   "proficiency": "Advanced Melee"
 }
```

With the JSON above I want to create and array in Swift:

```
let testArray: ["name", "price", "level"...]
```

I am still pretty new to playing with JSON in Swift and haven't found what I am looking for. Right now I am hard coding each array per object. I have a lot of different JSON files so being able to have something like this would help out alot.

Comment: Why an array, and not keep the dictionary? If you have parsed the JSON into an Dictionary (with `JSONSerialization`), you can easily retrieve the keys of the dictionaries (`myDict.keys`)

Comment: I thought about that, but I just realized that order does matter. The order in which I presented the JSON,  from top to bottom is the order it needs to be in. Unless there is a way to preserve the order and use a dictionary.

Comment: You can’t with native serialization. You have to implement your own parser.

Comment: There is no way to maintain order in a JSON object (dictionary). JSON object keys do not promise order, and Swift does not preserve it. Any JSON where the key order is semantically important violates the JSON spec. As Larme notes, you'll have to parse this "JSON-like encoding" by hand. Given that it's "JSON-like" you may be lucky and the output is exactly as you show here. If so, then you can easily split it by `\n` and then parse each line. It doesn't have to work for arbitrary JSON, because it isn't JSON.

Comment: Ok. I was afraid that was going to be the answer. No big deal really. I was wandering and as I stated before I am still new to JSON in swift, as a matter of fact to JSON itself.

Comment: but wait - if you're creating the JSON data yourself, why not add an index, then you can create the array, and sort it by that field - if you want to keep things tidy, you can strip out the index field when you create your sorted array

Comment: @Micheal It's very possible still. just create an struct that conforms to Decodable and have the order you wish like let name: String, let price: Int, let level: Int etc.. Then you have a computed property on this that generates an array. The way to do it is you use a the mirror feature `Mirror(reflect: Any)`

Comment: Dictionaries are not a great way to deal with structured data. If you are creating a model that will always contain the same set of fields, use an array of `struct`s rather than an array of `Dictionary`s.

Comment: So for this portion, the weapons, I have 4 different JSON files that make up All the weapons. All of them have those exact properties. The other 3 files have added properties to account for what those contain. So I have it subclassed into Melee, Ranged. Then even further if they use any kind of ammo/other source to make up the ammo. Then I will have other sections for different types of equipment and so on. But ALL files will all contain: name, level, price, source, bulk

Comment: if you don't mind me asking, why does the order matter for your use case?

Comment: Sorry got busy, because its for display purposes. Its for a reference app. I want consistency and the order shows the data with the important information to least important. Generally speaking the information I want first is generally the information that will be the same between all the different equipment type.